# jQuery UI's draggable textfield

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to have a draggable editable span, so I used jQuery UI `draggable` feature. Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#item").draggable();
});
```

```css
#item {
  min-width: 25px;
  border: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<span id="item" contenteditable="true">Item</span>
```

But now the issue is that I want to put my cursor wherever I want when I click on the span, but as of now when I click on it the cursor is always at the beginning. How should I do? I'm on Firefox Developer.

My idea was to add a border around the span to grab the element, and when the user clicks on the text it puts the cursor.

Comment: Advise wrapping it in a Div and make the Div draggable. Trying to "drag" a text field becomes very hard since it's looking for the click to take focus for the cursor. So the click for DnD has to battle it out with the browser click event and it will lose. Also helpful to use a handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".item-wrapper").draggable({
    handle: ".handle"
  });
});
```

```css
.item-wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #c2c2c2;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item-wrapper .handle {
  width: 10px;
}
#item {
  min-width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="item-wrapper">
  <span class="handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>
  <span id="item" contenteditable="true">Item</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.